# How to get objects from array of objects whose property "name" contains similar value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object,I need to get those objects only whose property "name" having similar value.I have provided the expected output also.Here is the code below.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>JavaScript</h2>
    <script>
    const value = 

    [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Pumpkin"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Ladies Finger"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Spinach"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Spinach"
        }
    ]
    console.log("get same value property")
   /*Expected output 
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Spinach"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Spinach"
    }
]
*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you expect the result to be? what have you tried so far?

Comment: [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Spinach"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Spinach"
    }
]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over array once to create the key value pairs to store the occurence of the elements. And then use this key value pair to filter out the array elements using filter function. Something like this

```
const dataKeyMaps = value.reduce((vl, e) => {
  vl[e.name] = ++vl[e.name] || 0;
  return vl;
}, {});
const duplicateObjects = value.filter(x => dataKeyMaps[x.name]);
```

```js
const value = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Pumpkin"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ladies Finger"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Spinach"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Spinach"
  }
]

const dataKeyMaps = value.reduce((vl, e) => {
  vl[e.name] = ++vl[e.name] || 0;
  return vl;
}, {});
const duplicateObjects = value.filter(x => dataKeyMaps[x.name]);
console.log(duplicateObjects)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Pumpkin"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ladies Finger"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Spinach"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Spinach"
  }
]

const tmp = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (acc[item.name])
    acc[item.name].push(item)
  else
    acc[item.name] = [item]

  return acc
}, {})

const result = Object.values(tmp).filter(i => i.length > 1).flat()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You should add some commentary to describe your code, and maybe link to some documentation for the methods you've used.

Comment: Great answer Taam!

Comment: I have already added expected output in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Good question!
https://jsfiddle.net/coder039/3fu87h6j/1/

```
const propertyCounter = () => {
  const data = {}
  return {
    add(item) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        data[item] = data[item] + 1
      } else {
        data[item] = 1
      }
    },
    get(item) {
      return data[item]
    },
    getData() {
      return data
    },
  }
}

const arr = [{
    id: 2,
    name: "Pumpkin",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Ladies Finger",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Spinach",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Spinach",
  },
]
const counter = propertyCounter()
arr.forEach((item) => {
  counter.add(item.name)
})

const result = arr.filter((obj) => counter.getData()[obj.name] >= 2)
console.log(result)
document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```